# Using a counter in VBA

Tags: excel, counter, vba

I'm working making a loop to get data out of a combo form.

`Analysis_`1 is the first variable 
`Analysis_1_ComboB` is the first `ComboBox` from the screen

```
Analysis_1 = Me.Analysis_1_ComboB.Column(0)
Analysis_2 = Me.Analysis_2_ComboB.Column(0)
Analysis_3 = Me.Analysis_3_ComboB.Column(0)
```

etc etc

as single lines, it is working I do want to work with a loop

```
for counter = 1 to 9
    Analysis_&Counter = Me.Analysis_&Counter&_ComboB.Column(0)
next counter
```

unfortunately, this is not working, who can help me out here?

Comment: You should use an array - perhaps `Dim Analysis(1 To 9) As String` and then use `Analysis(counter) = ...`.

Comment: @YowE3K don't be lazy, write this as an answer, you are close to the 10K mark

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you cannot dynamically specify variable names.  (You can usually find a way to dynamically access various objects, especially if they are accessible be a "Name" index.)

The best way to achieve what you want to do is make your variables an array, e.g.:

```
Dim Analysis(1 To 9) As String
For counter = 1 To 9
    Analysis(counter) = Me.Controls("Analysis_" & counter & "_ComboB").Column(0)
Next counter
MsgBox "Value from Analysis_5_ComboB is " & Analysis(5)
```

(This code assumes that your ComboBoxes are on a UserForm and therefore dynamically accessible via the form's `Controls` collection.)